# When kubernetes restarts a failed container, does it get a new container_id?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

When a container restarts in Kubernetes (due to exiting with a non-zero exit status), it will be restarted if unless I specify restartPolicy:never .

Question: will the new container get the same container id, or will it have a different one?
In my tests on KIND (K8s-in-Docker) it seems to get the same container id -- is this guaranteed?

Thanks, all.

Alex

Comment: What test exactly did you run?

Comment: Boy, so long ago that I don't remember, but I probably ran a shell script that sleeps and then does "exit 1" or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pod and container are ephemeral. If a pod gets recreated it gets a new ID. The same goes with container ID. You can check that in a few steps:

- Create a deployment, for example: `kubectl create deployment --image=nginx nginx-app`
- list the pods to see if the freshly created one is up and running: `kubectl get pods`
- see the container details of that pod with: `kubectl describe pod nginx-app-<pod_id>`, you can find the Container ID in section `Containers:`
- delete the pod with `kubectl delete pod nginx-app-<pod_id>` so the deployment can start another one in his place
- again see the details of the new nginx-app pod with `kubectl describe pod nginx-app-<new_pod_id>` and notice that it has a different Container ID

Comment: Strictly speaking, the steps you outlined wouldn't be proof that a container restarted in the same pod would get a new ID (though I agree that it does).